# Using same action to process and receive form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have an action like this:

```
def add_credit_card
    if request.post?
      unless params[:conditions]
        flash[:error] = 'You need to accept!'
      end
    end
end
```

This action renders the following view:

```
<%= form_tag do %>
  <fieldset>
      <%= check_box_tag "conditions"%> I agree to the <%= link_to "Terms and Conditions", consumer_terms_and_conditions_url, :target => "_blank" %>
  </fieldset>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

When I do a GET to that action no errors are shown. When I do a submit with that box checked no errors are shown.  When I do the first submit without that box checked the error is shown, but the problem comes when I do another submit and the checkbox is not checked, the errors are still there.

My questions are:

1. Why is that happening?
2. What would be a better approach to deal with this situation, where a form is not attached to a model and the errors have to be shown just when the user has submitted the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the same action, you'll want to use flash.now so the flash hash does not persist to the next action.

```
 flash.now[:error] = 'You need to accept!'
```

Also, it's not essential, but consider using:

```
 <%= check_box_tag 'conditions', 'accepted' %>
```

and then checking the value of the params[:conditions] for the string "accepted" i.e.:

```
 unless params[:conditions]=='accepted'
   flash.now[:error] = 'You need to accept!'
 end
```

Comment: Ah okay, I'll remove that from my initial soln.  I added another possible soln instead.

Comment: I finally got around to trying this, and the problem is the flash hash persisting to the next request. Since you're not redirecting you'll want to use flash.now